# PHP display arabic font in webservice response

Tags: php, codeigniter, character-encoding

I created webservice which generate response in Arabic language But it does not display in arabic font. It display ascii code like below.

```
{"data":[{"id":"1","name":"\u0627\u062e\u062a\u0628\u0627\u0631"}]}
```

So how can I shown arabic font in response? May I have to set any header for that?

Comment: Why do you care about what JSON looks like? You aren't supposed to show it to end user.

Comment: If I send this response to end user then He can convert it to Arabic?

Comment: The text is encoded in unicode, which can be read by web browser for sure (if proper encoding is set)

Comment: I got proper output using `echo json_encode($response,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);`

Comment: That [**is** Arabic](https://eval.in/577458), there's nothing to convert. And Web Services are designed to be consumed by programs, not people!